# VS Express for Windows Phone 7 and 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, sdk, windows-phone-8

Can we both install VS Express for Windows Phone 7 and VS Express for Windows phone 8 on Windows 8 ?

I've already installed the Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 8 but I also want to install the Windows Phone 7 SDK's (a question of compatibility in a team project).

Comment: Since you have installed vs express 2012(for wp8) when you install wp7 sdk, only sdk components would be installed. You can use wp7 and wp8 sdk simultaneously on same ide (vs express 2012).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows SDK 8.0 to develop apps for both WP7 and WP8. You need not to install both SDK's.

To know how to maintain the same version of app for both WP7 and WP8, read [this article](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_Silverlight_application)